# Where to find the corrected BLOSUM matrices?

Tags: bioinformatics, sequence-alignment

I was looking at [this paper](http://www.nature.com/nbt/journal/v26/n3/full/nbt0308-274.html) which talks about the miscalculations in the BLOSUM matrices and how the "wrong" BLOSUM62 matrix performs better than the corrected version. I was trying to find the corrected version they talk about to experiment with, but [the link they list in the paper](http://web.mit.edu/bamel/blosum/) appears dead.

Does anyone know where I can find the corrected matrix that the authors talk about?  (preferably a version listing frequencies rather than scores)

Comment: Either write to them asking for the files or see the images in the supplementary info (fig 4-5). They could have at least made it as a table; unfortunately you have to manually type it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I emailed Dr. Mark Styczynsk (one of the authors) to ask about a link to the matrix. Here are the links he gave me:

http://web.mit.edu/bamel/blosum/revised_blosum.c

http://web.mit.edu/bamel/blosum/original_blosum.c

http://web.mit.edu/bamel/blosum/RBLOSUM64 (isentropic with BLOSUM62)

http://web.mit.edu/bamel/blosum/RBLOSUM62 (not isentropic, but it's 62)

The first link is to the c code to generate the corrected BLOSUM. According to Mark, just replacing the original c file in [the original BLOSUM tarball](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/repository/blocks/unix/blosum/blosum.tar.Z) with the revised c file can generate the corrected matrix for any of the BLOSUMs (30, 50, 92). Haven't yet tried that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your question made it difficult to understand what you are looking for so I hope these two links will provide you with the desired data.

[0. A source link to the paper in question](http://phdtree.org/pdf/18073099-blosum62-miscalculations-improve-search-performance/) and its [supplementary file](http://web.mit.edu/bamel/blosum/styczynski2007supp.pdf).

[1. What blast is currently using.](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/repository/blocks/unix/blosum/blosum.tar.Z)

[2. What the math calls for.](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0098983#pone-0098983-g006)